# PL-SQL Oracle dbms_parallel_execute for partitioned tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, parallel-processing, partitioning

We have update one of our table which has around 150 million rows for each partition and such 12 partition exists . We want to use `dbms_parallel_execute` functionality to achieve this but I am not able to figure out how to pass partition specification for creating the chunks.

Please let me know if you have some pointers.

Comment: How many row are you updating?

Comment: I think you could try CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_SQL driving off the all_tab_partitions.HIGH_VALUE (and the know INTERVAL or range)  to return the START, END and CHUNK SIZE, and rely on Oracle optimiser being able to PRUNE the partitions accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Great idea of spiting data to equal size chunks.
May be scary at first look but really works.
You can adopt them to your update with dbms_parallel_execute.

https://stewashton.wordpress.com/2015/07/01/splitting-a-table-into-rowid-ranges-of-equal-size/